# Windows cmake build configuration with spaces in compiler path

Tags: cmake

I am trying to configure cmake build with following command:-

```
 cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=d:\buildbot-worker\worker\llvm-main-nvptx-win/install -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=llvm;mlir -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON -DLLVM_LIT_ARGS=-vv -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86;NVPTX -DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=nvptx-nvidia-cuda -DLLVM_OPTIMIZED_TABLEGEN=ON -DMLIR_ENABLE_CUDA_RUNNER=1 -DMLIR_INCLUDE_INTEGRATION_TESTS=1 -DMLIR_RUN_CUDA_TENSOR_CORE_TESTS=1 -DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER="C:\Program Files\Test Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2/bin/nvcc" -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=/manifest:no -DCMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS=/manifest:no -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS=/manifest:no -Wno-dev d:\test-worker\worker\llvm-main-nvptx-win/llvm
```

I am facing below issue :-

```
CMake Error at D:/buildbot-worker/worker/llvm-main-nvptx-win/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.1/CMakeCUDACompiler.cmake:1 (set):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    D:/buildbot-worker/worker/llvm-main-nvptx-win/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.1/CMakeCUDACompiler.cmake:1

  when parsing string

    C:\Program Files\Test Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2/bin/nvcc

  Invalid character escape '\P'.
```

Looks like passing `-DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER="C:\Program Files\Test Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2/bin/nvcc"` causing problems because of having spaces in path. How can i work around this ? Though i try to enclose it in `"` , I face the same issue.

Comment: "causing problems because of having spaces in path." - Eh? The error message - `Invalid character escape '\P'` is clearly about the **backslash**. Try to replace all backslashes in variable `CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER` with forward slashes. Normally, CMake automatically transforms paths, specified in the command line, from *native style* (on Windows this style uses backslashes) to the *cmake-style*, with forward slashes only. But it seems that in your case transformation hasn't take a place.

Comment: yes, I try to replace backslashes with forward slashes. Still hit the same issue.

Comment: If you replaced `C:\Program Files\Test Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2/bin/nvcc` with `C:/Program Files/Test Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.2/bin/nvcc`, then the error cannot be the *same*: there is no `\P` sequence in the resulted path.